# how to fool jqXHR to succeed always

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make jQuery's ajax calls always return as if they succeeded,
e.g. even when I don't have network, I will return some locally saved data

It that possible?

I tried using the $.ajaxPrefilter and calling the success function of the jqXHR,
but still it won't behave as if the request has finished :(

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to do it that way? If you want to return local data as a fallback, why not do the natural thing and utilize the error handler to activate the fallback?

Comment: I want that behavior so when i return local data on the fallback, I want this to be transparent, as if the request succeeded

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, a quick update: non of the solutions above worked.
What I eventually had to do to walk around this problem, is replace jQuery's ajax function with my implementation, that checks if there is network connection.
if there is, I proxy the request back to the original ajax function, else, I create the same return structure as ajax's would and return it

Again, I hate answering my own questions, especially when it's not really an answer but more of a workaround.
sad...

Comment: try my response below... I think it might help :)

Answer (score 3):

If im understanding you correctly, you want to make the jqXHR act like it succeeded, when it actually failed?

If so, .pipe is your friend :)

```
var jqDeferred = $.ajax(...something something);

//make the deferred always resolve as success, calling all success callbacks on original.
//AFAIK, dosent pass any arguments to the original success callbacks.
jqDeferred.pipe( null, function(args){ return $.Deferred().resolve(); });

//same as above, but try to pass all arguments through to the success callbacks.
jqDeferred.pipe( null, function(args){ return $.Deferred().resolve.apply(this, arguments); });
```

I wanted to do this recently and couldnt find any easy instructions, hope it helps.
Im not super sure about the argument passing, as I have only used the first form in anger - we didn't need any arguments passed to our success callbacks.

Pipe is wicked.

Comment: As of jQuery 1.8, pipe is deprecated. See write-up in [jQuery Deferred then](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should handle that ajax error with any code for your needs.

> **error(jqXHR, textStatus,
>   errorThrown)**
>
> > Function A function to be
> >     called if the request fails. The
> >     function receives three arguments: The
> >     jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x,
> >     XMLHttpRequest) object, a string
> >     describing the type of error that
> >     occurred and an optional exception
> >     object, if one occurred. Possible
> >     values for the second argument
> >     (besides null) are "timeout", "error",
> >     "abort", and "parsererror". When an
> >     HTTP error occurs, errorThrown
> >     receives the textual portion of the
> >     HTTP status, such as "Not Found" or
> >     "Internal Server Error." As of jQuery
> >     1.5, the error setting can accept an array of functions. Each function will
> >     be called in turn. Note: This handler
> >     is not called for cross-domain script
> >     and JSONP requests. This is an Ajax
> >     Event.

Example

```
 error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
            if (err.Message == 'SomeMessage') {
               //Return Your data, handle this error...
            }
        }
```

Comment: I have a way of finding if I have access to the url of the request without waiting for it to timeout, and I don't want the user to wait until timeout

Comment: You could set timeout to 0 if you know that your url is not accessible. Try that if it will work...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.ajaxSetup](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) with your own custom `beforeSend` handler. In your handler you can check if the url is accesible, if it's not you can cancel the request and emulate a call to success with your own data.

Comment: thanks, my question is how to emulate that success call. can you please provide an example?

Comment: I'll try to get a working fiddle when I'll have some time soon

Comment: For now I guess you can retrieve the handler for `success` from the settings object you get with the `beforeSend` handler.

Comment: as I said, I did call the success func. but appears that calling it alone does not produce the same affect as a successful ajax call (i still get timeout for one...)

Comment: What do you mean ? did you cancel the original XHR?