# How to trick a jqXHR to resolve using local data?

Tags: jquery, ajax, promise, jqxhr

This is similar to this question [Make jquery jqxhr act like already sending request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27620885/make-jquery-jqxhr-act-like-already-sending-request?lq=1) but that doesn't seem to solve my problem.

I'm using a framework where there are lots of requests done using jQuery ajax methods, and I have to hook in the middle of that (but without touching the original code) to emulate some responses from the server.

With [ajaxSend](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxsend/) I can detect whenever a request is being send, so at that point I know which ones I want to stop and provide my precomputed response, but I can't find a way to do it. One possible deep level alternative would be to ignore jQuery and go for a Service Worker, but that would restrict the browsers where this will work and it can mean also added complexity to the logic about the precomputed responses, so I would like to stay with a jQuery solution.

For starters I would be happy to have a first step just by being able to stop the request from touching the network, but although I tried to stop the event, the xhr is always executed.

```
    $( document ).ajaxSend(function(event, request, settings) {
        console.log(request)
        event.preventDefault()
        event.stopPropagation()
        return false;
    }
```

Then the next step (or may it's this one) is using the request object to resolve the promise, but it doesn't have a 'resolve' method, so I guess that it's a [restricted Promise](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.resolve/)

Can anyone help me to find a solution?

Comment: I guess you'll need to decorate (overwrite) `$.ajax` itself.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar to this a while back by overriding `$.ajax`.

```
(function ($) {
    var jqAjax = $.ajax;
    $.ajax = function (settings) {
        if(someCriteriaToDetermineIfItsLocalOrNot) {
           // get from local storage, and return a promise or something
        } else
            return jqAjax(settings);
    };
} (jQuery));
```